# DateTime.ParseExact Returns Wrong Value

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am trying to add hour and minute into the returning value of a datepicker(wpf). I think there is something wrong with my date format parameter for ParseExact(), but couldnt get where the problem is.

```
string[] timeAndDate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(dPicker.SelectedDate.ToString(), " ");
string time = cmbTime.SelectedItem.ToString();
string tempDT = timeAndDate[0] + " " + time;
DateTime queryDT = DateTime.ParseExact(tempDT, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It keeps returning minValue 01.01.0001 etc. Its probably about these time dots. I also tried to add seconds but still no luck.

Btw tempDT is kinda "22.12.2016 20:30"

my input string is "22.12.2016 20:30"
method returns {01.01.0001 00:00:00}

I am also doing this to get two dates from datepickers and get two hour variables via two comboboxes, and make two datetime objects to send them to sql.

It seems I didnt put the debug point on the right place, embarrising but anyway, thanks so much!

Comment: please show your input string.s

Comment: What do you mean "is kinda"? What is `tempDT` exactly?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact("22.12.2016 20:30", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` returns `{12/22/2016 8:30:00 PM}` for me. What is the *actual* value you're passing in? The actual definite confirmed no-foolin' value, not a guess or inference. P.S. @rboe is right, the whole thing is a pointless exercise in self-hazing.

Comment: Or... in other words.... debug your code.

Comment: There is no need to convert the DateTime of dPicker.SelectedDate to a string and manipulate it via string operations. What's about working with the DateTime type directly. I do not know exactly, what you want to achieve, so please clarify your post.

Comment: tempDT = "22.12.2016 02.00"
queryDT = {01.01.0001 00:00:00}

Comment: @SelcukSZR Are you saying that "01.01.0001 00:00:00" parses correctly?

Comment: @SelcukSZR You have a . in the time instead of a :. The input string should either have 02:00 or change your format string.

Comment: @SelcukSZR your input uses a dot to separate hours/minutes. Your format expects a colon

Comment: can you show the value of dPicker.SelectedDate.ToString()?

Comment: well so sorry friends, it seems i put the debug point at the wrong row...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't need to parse the date at all; the date picker exposes the selected date as a System.DateTime already.  You still have to parse the time because it is being held in a combo box instead of a [TimePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/time-picker) for some reason.

Instead of

```
string[] timeAndDate = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(dPicker.SelectedDate.ToString(), " ");
string time = cmbTime.SelectedItem.ToString();
string tempDT = timeAndDate[0] + " " + time;
DateTime queryDT = DateTime.ParseExact(tempDT, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

why not write

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse(cmbTime.SelectedItem.ToString());
DateTime queryDT = dPicker.SelectedDate.Add(ts);
```

Comment: I tried AddHours() but didnt wanna double type get involved. I can use your method, thanks very much!

Comment: btw as far as I know, wpf doesnt have a vanilla TimePicker, am I wrong?

Comment: @SelcukSZR It doesnt have vanilla, but if you are not adverse to using it the Extended WPF toolkit has a DateTimePicker control - http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Home